# Vim gets stucked when I paste

Tags: vim

I `yy` some text from one file, and then `p` in the other file, vim stucked!

I use

1. iTerm2 Build 2.9.20160313
2. VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 23 2016 16:54:02)
   MacOS X (unix) version
   Included patches: 1-1345
   Compiled by Homebrew

Comment: What do you mean with "stucked"? Also note that by default `yy` doesn't copy to the OS' clipboard (unless you configured Vim to do so), so if you're pasting it in another Vim instance it's expected that it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you copying to another file? Are you copying from one buffer to another or you have 2 terminals and you're copying in one and pasting in another (sic!). How does the vim get stucked? Provide more information because it's impossible to answer with only that...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker they are in one instance. @lewiatan may get the point: 'I  copy from one buffer, and paste it in other one, they both buffer (I use `command-T` plugin)'. **stucked** means I can do nothing with my kbd,`jhkl `and so on. I'm poor in English :P

Comment: are you sure you're not accidentally hitting ``ctrl+s`` ?  try hitting ``ctrl+q`` and see if that unfreeze your terminal.

Comment: @Meitham I'm sure I didn't hit those keys, (I need 2 fingers to do that :)). And I also tried `ctrl+q`.